# animation doesn't work in second iteration in firefox

Tags: jquery, css, animation, mozilla

i was making a slider with some animations, it's working in google chrome, but in firefox, it works well at first (showing images for the first time)
but when it starts to show the images for the second time, i can't see the animation

here is jquery code

```
var anim = function(index){
    return _start = setInterval(function(){
        $($slides).each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("current");
        });
        $($pages).each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        });
        if(index < $slides.length - 1)
            index++;
        else
            index = 0;
        current = index;
        $($slides[index]).addClass("current");
        $($pages[index]).addClass("active");
    },speed);
}
```

### it's like firefox remembers the animation and it doesnt show it again

here is 'current' class in CSS

```
.current{display: block;}
.current .right-side img{
    animation:zoomin 5s;
    -moz-animation:zoomin 5s;
    -webkit-animation:zoomin 5s;
    -o-animation:zoomin 5s;
    -ms-animation:zoomin 5s;
}
.current .right-side img{
    animation:zoomin 5s;
    -webkit-animation:zoomin 5s;
    -moz-animation:zoomin 5s;
    -o-animation:zoomin 5s;
    -ms-animation:zoomin 5s;
}
.current .left-side > *:not(button) {
    animation:fadeInDown 2.5s;
    -moz-animation:fadeInDown 2.5s;
    -webkit-animation:fadeInDown 2.5s;
    -o-animation:fadeInDown 2.5s;
    -ms-animation:fadeInDown 2.5s;
}
.current .left-side > button{
    animation : fadeIn 2.5s;
    -webkit-animation : fadeIn 2.5s;
    -moz-animation : fadeIn 2.5s;
    -o-animation : fadeIn 2.5s;
    -ms-animation : fadeIn 2.5s;
}
```

Comment: Please set up an example in jsfiddle, plunker, jsbin or codepen.

Answer (score 0):

Looking on line I think you need an iteration counter. Like this one.

```
animation-iteration-count: infinite;

animation-duration: 2.5s;
```

Comment: it works for the image animation, because it has 5sec same as setInterval duration... but the text has 2.5sec, so it repeats animation twice ... is there a possibility to stop animation for 2.5sec after it's complete for the text ?